# Set custom font to Dialog Preferences

Tags: android, typeface, dialog-preference

I created custom dialog to get input from users extending **DialogPreferences** class for setting. i need to change font used in dialog and external font using typeface. i set the font to massage using following code. but i couldn't set it for title because i couldn't find the title view also buttons( id of title and buttons).

```
      Text View message = (Text View)view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
      message.setTypeface(font);
```

how can i do this?
thank you.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Show your layout xml file and some more code.

Comment: i want to set font to default title of dialog. title is not set by layout. it is default one. so i can't find title text view to set font. so how can do this.

Comment: Maybe this [page](http://mysoftdevs.blogspot.it/2011/12/android-how-to-create-dialogpreference.html) helps you a bit. It's about a custom DialogPreference

Comment: thanks for your research. but it doesn't describe how to set font to default title. is there any way to do that. i just need to find title view and assign it to text view. so then i can set typeface.